# Read in a file which has part of the file name changing

Tags: r

I have some file names which look like the following;

Year1:

```
blds_PANEL_DPK_8237_8283
blds_PANEL_DPR_8237_8283
blds_PANEL_MWK_8237_8283
```

Which are all located in the same file path. However in a different file path for a different year I have very similar files;

Year 2:

```
blds_PANEL_MHG_9817_9876
blds_PANEL_HKG_9817_9876
blds_PANEL_DPR_9817_9876
```

Some of the files have the same names as the previous years yet some of the names change. The only part of the name which changes is the `MHG`, `HKG`, `DPR` sections of the name, the `blds_PANEL_` stays the same along with `9817_9876`.

I have created a `paste0()`

```
file_path = C:/Users...
product = blds
part_which_keeps_changing = HKG
weeks = 9817_9876

read.csv(paste0(file_path, product, product, part_which_keeps_changing, weeks, ".DAT"), header = TRUE)
```

It was working well for one product, however for new products I am running into some errors. So I am trying to load in data which perhaps ignores this part of the file name.

EDIT: This seems to solve what I am looking to do

```
temp <- list.files(paste0(files, product), pattern = "*.DAT")

location <- paste0(files, product, temp)

myfiles = lapply(location, read.csv)

library(plyr)
df <- ldply(myfiles, data.frame)
```

How ever I am running into a slightly different problem for some of the files.

If I have the following;

```
blds_PANEL_DPK_8237_8283
blds_PANEL_DPR_8237_8283
blds_PANEL_MWK_8237_8283
```

It is possible that one of the files contains no information and when I apply `lapply` it breaks and stops loading in the data when loading in the data.

Is it possible to skip over these files. Heres the error:

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  no lines available in input
```

EDIT 2:

This seems to overrde the `lapply` errors:

```
lapply_with_error <- function(X,FUN,...){    
  lapply(X, function(x, ...) tryCatch(FUN(x, ...),
                                      error=function(e) NULL))
}

myfiles = lapply_with_error(location, read.delim)
```

Comment: Have you looked at `?list.files`

Comment: I have applied the following;

`temp <- list.files(paste0(files, product), pattern = "*.DAT")
myfiles = lapply(temp, read.CSV)` However my file type is .DAT and it is telling me that there is no such file or directory.

Comment: Okay, this seems to import them as a list `temp <- list.files(paste0(files, product), pattern = "*.DAT")

location <- paste0(files, product, temp)

myfiles = lapply(location, read.csv)`

Comment: However now, when there is no data in the files I am trying to import, the `lapply` function stops importing.